# How to link external libraries in Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, libxml2, icu

I'm pretty new to Android (to be precise 1 day), so please bear with the explanation,:)

The requirement is to port the existing code (C & C++) which is working on iOS to Android.
Almost everything went well, except 'libxml2'. The code is dependent on this. And as one of the suggestions got from this very forum, I got the source code of 'libxml2 and compiled it for Android. But when trying to create a Shared library of it, its not able to resolve the external dependencies. Its throwing an error "undefined reference to 'ucnv_close', 'ucnv_open',...", for almost every function dependent on "ucnv_*".

I think "ucnv_*" comes as "icu4c" external library. I tried to compile this too, but in vain. This is throwing errors "'dynamic_cast' not permitted with -fno-rtti" and "cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti". I'm totally clue less here (don't exactly know on enabling / disabling the flag "-fno-rtti" and also its significance), and also don't prefer to hack around a well written code.

So, can anyone please explain on how to link (shared & static) / integrate the external libraries specially "libxml2" (also "icu4c" if required) with C/C++ code,.??? (I saw explanations on *.jar, but couldn't get how it'll fit here)
Any information to resolve / understand the problem I'm facing will be really helpful,..!!!

Thanks for reading,..